# entityFIeldQuery on user table, how can I add a condition for $user->data

Tags: 7, entities

I have tried extending EntitiyFieldQuery to add a condition that would be able to match on a `$user->data["somevar"]`, but to no avail. I am not sure this is even possible, as  `$user->data` is serialised.

I have just the base class working, returing users with status set to 1:

```
class SubscriberEntityFieldQuery extends EntityFieldQuery {
  // define some defaults for the class
  public function __construct() {
    // now we don't need to define these over and over anymore
    $this
      ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
  }
}
```

Would anyone have an idea if this is even possible? Or would I need to resort to using db_query for a case like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` column contains a serialized PHP string, which MySQL doesn't understand. As far as MySQL is concerned the data is just a string like any other.

Because of that you won't be able to query the properties of the serialized objects in that column without doing some seriously nasty work with `SUBSTRING`/regex/insert-other-unreliable-method-here.

If possible you should add a field to the user entity instead that represents the same data, and use the `EntityFieldQuery` with that field. It might not be ideal but it's probably the easiest solution.

Comment: Yes. This was my first impression also. I avoided extra user fields and implemented as a data variable to prevent having extra profile fields for not-often accessed data. Thanks friend.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need [`fieldCondition`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3afieldCondition/7) like the one below

```
class SubscriberEntityFieldQuery extends EntityFieldQuery {
  // define some defaults for the class
  public function __construct() {
    // now we don't need to define these over and over anymore
    $this
      ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
      ->fieldCondition('field_data_field_yourcustomuserfield', 'value', 'whatever-value-you-are-looking-for', '=')
  }
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not in a custom field. The variable is set in $user-­­>data, in a serialised state.

Comment: Oh man variable_get does not match well with fields API. Is there a way you can attach that variable data into a custom field, into the user entity, programatically? [These](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7?no_cache=1344343850) are all the apis available.

Comment: Custom fields add an extra table to user profile, these add quite a bit more overhead than `$user->data` .  When your profile has a lot of bits of data associated to a profile, you will find `$user->data` to be a nice lightweight alternative.  Unfortunately, you sometimes have to dive through hoops to get to it.

Comment: What you are saying is correct. But since this is user specific task, it needs to live in the fields. If you have 100,000 users then doing variable_get will prove a bit expensive in the long run.

Comment: No, friend. `variable_get()` is not used to get at `$user-­­­>data`. It is available in `$user` object after a `user_load()`. Say you have 15 extra data units to associate with a user profile, having 15 extra tables to join on is overkill, so we chose to store the less frequently accessed ones in $user->data, that is somewhat what it is meant to be used for in the first place.

Comment: aah user object, sure. Then the best way would be to wrap your query inside if else statement like this `global $user; if($user->data == compare){query style one} else{query style 2}`

Comment: No, my friend. I am looping through an array of uid's, `global $user` puts the currently logged on user in scope. Hey. I upvoted you for your input though, will post my workaround when I have a few minutes.

Comment: There is one small problem with your code and that is variable `$user` is reserved for user who is logged in. If you are referring to some other account other than the one who is logged in, then you must use `$account` variable. So it should be $account->data. This is specific to drupal only and not php. This concept comes from [Drupal 7 Module Development](http://www.packtpub.com/drupal-7-module-development/book) book.

Comment: I would love to know what solution you could come up with. This is very interesting one.